# Regex find whole substring between parenthesis containing exact substring

Tags: python, regex, string, substring, parentheses

For example I have string:

```
"one two  (78-45ack sack); now (87 back sack) follow dollow (59 uhhaaa)"
```

and I need only whole substring with parenthesis, containing word `"back"`, for this string it will be:

```
"(87 back sack)"
```

I've tried:

```
(\(.*?back.*?\))
```

but it's return `"(78-45ack sack); now (87 back sack)"`

How should my regex look like? As I understood it's happening cause search going from begin of the string, in common - **how to perform regex to `"search"` from the middle of string, from the word `"back"`?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this regex based on negated character class:

```
\([^()]*?back[^()]*\)
```

- `[^()]*` matches 0 or more of any character that is not `(` and `)`, thus making sure we don't match across the pair of `(...)`.

[RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/hX7yW2/3)

---

Alternatively, you can also use this regex based on negative regex:

```
\((?:(?!back|[()]).)*?back[^)]*\)
```

[RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/hX7yW2/4)

- `(?!back|[()])` is negative lookahead that asserts that current position doesn't have `back` or `(` or `)` ahead in the text.
- `(?:(?!back|\)).)*?` matches 0 or more of any character that doesn't have `back` or `(` or `)` ahead.
- `[^)]*` matches anything but `)`.

Comment: Really Impressive! how do you get these ideas?

Comment: Why did you include a left parenthesis in the negated character class?

Comment: To take care of unbalanced pair of `(...)` e.g. `one two  (78-45ack sack; now (87 back sack) follow dollow (59 uhhaaa)`

Comment: I shoulda looked at your demo.

Comment: Can you explain why the "non-capture" `(?:` and lazy `*?` are necessary?  For my problem, I tried `print\(((?!file=mylog)[^)])*\)`, which didn't work, but then `print\((?:(?!file=mylog)[^)])*?\)`, which did.

Answer (score 0):

```
h="one two  (78-45ack sack); now (87 back sack) follow dollow (59 uhhaaa)"
l=h.split("(")
[x.split(")")[0] for x in l if ")" in x and "back" in x]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below pattern for reluctant matching

pattern="\(.*?\)"